# Outer automorphism group of $SL_2(\mathbb{F_{p}})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, automorphism-group

I am trying to prove that

$$Out(SL_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{p})) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2}$$

for $p$ prime, but I have no clue where I should start, can anyone help me?

Comment: You might want to look at the comment of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3279987/665815).

Comment: Maybe this link is of some interest: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Element_structure_of_special_linear_group_of_degree_two_over_a_finite_field . Moreover for $2 \times 2$ matrices the map $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ -c & d \end{pmatrix} $ seems to be an outer automorphism.

Comment: The question linked by @withoutfeather got deleted and is probably not visible to everyone. The comment they allude to was: "This is proved in Dieudonne, La géométrie des groupes classiques. – 
Dietrich Burde
Jul 1, 2019 at 18:48"